# NSOutlineview with checkbox

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa-bindings

I am looking to add checkboxes to NSOutlineview with bindings using as the basis this project https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html

How do I add the behavour to allow users whereby if I click a parent checkbox, then it will select the children, and if I unclick it - it will deselect the children of that item?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question, how to add a checkbox, how to connect the checkbox to an action method or how to select the children? Do you want to store the value of the checkbox? Do you want to select the rows of the children or do you want to select the checkboxes of the children?

Comment: How to select/unselect checkboxes of the children when parent checkbox is select/unselect

Comment: Is the value of the checkbox stored in the data?

Comment: I've added to basenode class a BOOL property called selected. I've removed the outlinedatasourcedelegate. Now i'm using data bindings. That's work good, but now i can't figure out how to works checkbox with parent/children

Comment: I'm working in objective c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect the action of the checkbox to an action method of the delegate of the outline view. In the action method, set the property of the child nodes and reload the item and children.

```
- (IBAction)checkboxAction:(id)sender {
    NSInteger row = [self.myOutlineView rowForView:sender];
    if (row >= 0) {
        id item = [self.myOutlineView itemAtRow:row];
        if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSTreeNode class]]) {
            BaseNode *node = [item representedObject];
            if ([node isKindOfClass:[BaseNode class]]) {
                for (BaseNode *child in node.children)
                    child.isSelected = node.isSelected;
                [self.myOutlineView reloadItem:item reloadChildren:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this code works good, but now if I've another parent to the child, that will not be selected. Look the picture https://imgur.com/a/3dctuKa

Comment: I solved replacing node.children to node.descendants. Now the next step is when all checkbox are checked and if i uncheck one, the parent checkbox should become in mixedstate mode